# Scope issue in extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, scope, extjs4

I have this treepanel and i want to call `this.getId()` method of mainpaneltree from inside "Expand all" button But all i get is method undefined.I tried to put `scope:this`in config objects but no success.

```
Ext.define('MA.view.patient.Tree', {
extend : 'Ext.tree.Panel',
alias : 'widget.EditPatientTree',
title : 'Simple Tree',
width : 150,
store:'Tree',
dockedItems : [ {
    xtype : 'toolbar',
    items : [ {
        text : 'Expand All',
        scope: this,
        handler : function() {
    //this.expandAll gives "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'getId'"
            this.expandAll();
   //the same error for this.getId();
            this.getId();
        }
    } ]
} ],
rootVisible : false,
initComponent : function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

So my question is how to get reference to the current component and call its methods while you are inside nested methods or config objects of current component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The handler has arguments that are passed in, 1 of them is normally the button.  From the button you can get the container.

```
Ext.define('MA.view.patient.Tree', {
extend : 'Ext.tree.Panel',
alias : 'widget.EditPatientTree',
title : 'Simple Tree',
width : 150,
store:'Tree',
dockedItems : [ {
    xtype : 'toolbar',
    items : [ {
        text : 'Expand All',
        scope: this,
        handler : function(button, event) {
            var toolbar = button.up('toolbar'), treepanel = toolbar.up('treepanel');
            treepanel.expandAll();
            treepanel.getId();
        }
    } ]
} ],
rootVisible : false,
initComponent : function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the methods like `up`, `down` for get references of components that are parent or child. In your case, you could get the reference of the tree panel by:

```
myTree = this.up('treepanel');
```

Similarly, you could use the `down` method, to get hold of any child reference.